# \textcolor not changing the href text color

Tags: color, text, href

I have set the href color for the whole document to blue, href text color of top part of document has indeed changed but I have added two minipage in the document, and href text color is not taking effect in the minipage. I tried changing the \color and \textcolor of individual texts as well, but it is not working at all.

Here's example code:

```latex
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
 
\begin{document}

\namesection{Debarghya}{Das}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{http://debarghyadas.com}{debarghyadas.com}| \href{http://fb.co/dd}{fb.co/dd}\\
\href{mailto:deedy@fb.com}{deedy@fb.com} | 607.379.5733 | \href{mailto:dd367@cornell.edu}{dd367@cornell.edu}
}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 

\section{Links} 
Facebook:// \href{https://facebook/dd}{\bf dd} \\
Github:// \href{https://github.com/deedydas}{\bf deedydas} \\
LinkedIn://  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/debarghyadas}{\bf debarghyadas} \\
YouTube://  \href{https://www.youtube.com/user/DeedyDash007}{\bf DeedyDash007} \\
Twitter://  \href{https://twitter.com/debarghya_das}{\bf @debarghya\_das} \\
Quora://  \href{https://www.quora.com/Debarghya-Das}{\bf Debarghya-Das}

\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 

\section{Experience}
\runsubsection{\href{https://facebook.com/}{Facebook}}
\descript{| \textcolor{blue}{Software Engineer} }
\location{Jan 2015 - Present | New York, NY}
\sectionsep

\end{minipage} 
\end{document}
```

Here's the viewing link of whole document, in case there is a problem with anything else: https://www.overleaf.com/read/vvpchrnntzqb

Edit: I rechecked it. Actually I'm not able to change the color of any text in the minipage. This is happening inside the minipage only, I'm able to change the text outside the minipage, in other parts of the document.

Comment: I have edited the question and added an example. But I have added a link in the bottom, because I'm not sure whether it is a problem of the main code or .cls file or anything else.

Comment: if i comment out the fonts I dont have [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoEMp.png) what did you want?

Comment: perhaps comment out hidelinks option? `\usepackage
%[hidelinks]
{hyperref}`

Comment: Don't use `{\bf <stuff>}` to set your stuff bold. Instead use `\textbf{<stuff>}`!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  it isn't working with hyperlink though:     \runsubsection{\textcolor{blue}{\href{https://facebook.com/}{Facebook}}}      or       \runsubsection{\href{https://facebook.com/}{\textcolor{blue}{Facebook}}}
commenting out the hidelinks option is also not working,

Comment: @Skillmon setting stuff bold is not the problem, i also tried not using bold at all., it is still not working.

Comment: why can you not simply use the hyperref options to colour links?

Comment: @A.Vats perhaps you misunderstood me: While this is not your actual problem, it is *wrong* to use `\bf` to get bold text. That command is deprecated (**for more than 10 years**). Either use `\textbf{<stuff>}` or `{\bfseries <stuff>}`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @Skillmon

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried the hyperref option to color links in the beginning itself. But it only colored the links in document that was not inside minipage. The links inside minipage are not getting colored by the hyperref option.